# How to prevent Project ASP.NET Configuration and Team Foundation Server from fighting

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005

So, I am using visual studio 2005 (and team explorer 2005) with tfs 2008.  I have installed both Visual Studio 2005 SP1 and VS80sp1-KB932544-X86-ENU.exe.

I perform the following steps:

1. Select Project->ASP.NET Configuration within Visual Studio 2005.
2. Within Visual Studio 2005, attempt to perform either a check-in or a checkout.

The following happens:
The local server started by Visual Studio starts closing itself.  I suspect it is crashing; the systray icons are not properly disposed of.  It then reopens itself.  It does this over and over again, maybe once every second or two.  The TFS progress meter doesn't even budge, it just sits there.  Canceling out of the checkout does not work; it says it is cancelling and does nothing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to make a change in the ASP.NET configuration, then check it in? Or are you talking about checking anything in when it's open? When you say "local server started by Visual Studio", are you talking about the local development server (cassini)? Maybe TFS is trying to save/access something it is using, causing it to crash.

Have you tried stopping all instances of the dev server *before* checking stuff in/out?

Comment: Stopping all instances of the dev server before checking stuff in/out will, of course, prevent this issue.  However, that is annoying.  I'm using the ASP.NET configuration to mess around with the database back end (e.g. delete users and create roles).  It does need read access to the web.config file to do this, but it doesn't actually do any writing to files that are part of the solution itself.